# CoffeeScript in Rails does not correctly render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, render

```
$('#some').append('<%= render 'my_partial' %>')
```

And it renders it as text. It always escapes html. I have tried in all ways to avoid escaping.

```
$('#some').append('<%= j render('my_partial') %>')
$('#some').append('<%= raw render('my_partial') %>')
```

Result is the same.

Comment: Try with double quotes. `$('#some').append("<%= j render('my_partial') %>")` and let me know if it is worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your coffee (or any files) to be interpreted as ERB, then you need to append the file name with .erb ie `app.coffee.erb`.

But a better question is why?  Doing so will tightly couple your coffee to both rails and ruby making re-use much harder - much like putting css inline in HTML.

There are two better options IMO:

1. Use data attributes in HTML and access them with javascript
2. If you only have a single variable to pass, try something like `<%= javascript_tag "my_func(#{@my_var})" %>`.  This will invoke a javascript function with that variable.

Comment: It works fine without erb extension except the moment I have described.